# Consul running on Docker HTTP health check returns "connection reset by peer"

Tags: go, docker, consul

We are running consul through docker and using the HTTP health checks to a URL (https://10.1.24.68:5012/status) with a self-signed certificate. However, I get the following error:

> 2016/06/10 10:29:42 [WARN] agent: http request failed
>   'https://10.1.24.68:5012/status': Get https://10.1.24.68:5012/status:
>   read tcp 10.3.2.11:55549->10.1.24.68:5012: read: connection reset by
>   peer

It works as well when we use the Script health check with the `wget` command but this is not ideal. [This](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul/blob/14ec46b3cf8edf6fdd3f4bda8deacdfb6d4e9a73/command/agent/check.go#L426) is the line of code in Consul throwing the above error.

When running the health check to a HTTP URL (http://localhost:5012/status) it works. Could this be a certificate issue? I've added our certificate to both `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` and `/usr/share/local/ca-certificates.crt`.

Halp!

Comment: According to the 40 line: Five types are supported: Script, HTTP, TCP, Docker and TTL
There is no "HTTPS" type.